# Some apps do not detect an internet connection

Tags: applications, internet, samsung-galaxy-a5

I've got a bit of a bizarre problem with my Android phone:

My internet connection is working and fully functional, since Chrome and most other apps have no problems. However, some apps do not detect an internet connection. They display 'No internet connection' errors or similar. Some apps do this far more frequently than others, and some can reconnect randomly.

Here are some observations:

- My banking app does this almost every time I want to check it.
- Various messaging apps will receive messages hours late (sometimes).
- This issue is temporarily resolved on reboot, and for some time all apps can connect to the internet.
- Terminating a process and relaunching it does not let it reconnect to the internet.
- Some apps can be using the internet just fine at the same time that others are not.
- Some apps never do this, such as Chrome, Google, various games and others.

As far as I can tell, it has existed since I got the phone a few months ago. I've tried disabling Samsung's battery manager in case it is messing with apps to save power.

I'm currently running my phone in safe mode - but it's unclear if this has had any effect yet.

I'm on WiFi, and I don't use mobile data. I own a VPN app but it's almost never enabled (except when traveling). The VPN app is one of the badly affected apps. Other devices on the same WiFi network do not show similar issues, and this problem occurs on any WiFi network.

Any advice on how to fix or troubleshoot this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this happen on Wifi or data connection?

Comment: Are you using any VPN app, ad blocker, firewall or the like?

Comment: I'm on WiFi, and I don't use data. I own a VPN app but it's almost never enabled (except when traveling). The VPN app is one of the badly affected apps.

Comment: I would say you should try using the apps with the vpn enabled. That way, if the WiFi is blocking certain apps, the vpn will get around that

Comment: @Abochur I'd agree – were there not the fact that "The VPN app is one of the badly affected apps", which I read as it cannot reach out itself.

Comment: Slightly related, linking mostly i have similar issues and it seems really really hard to find ANY information on some apps, not all apps, connectivity problems.https://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-s6-edge/552884-certain-apps-not-working-wifi-but-work-mobile-data.html

Comment: I have exactly the same problem since the android 12 upgrade. It does not seem related to battery, blockers, etc. Restart does not help. Affects both wifi and data plan connections. The weirdest is that the device indisputably has internet access (e.g. Browser), but not in certain apps. Also the problem comes and goes..

Answer (score 0):

It's either iptables, DNS, or battery optimization-related problems.
Because you've Knox on your Samsung device, acquiring root privilege is not an option in regard to warranty.

By the way, is your device activated with MDM? If it is, your administrator has enforced firewall policy configuration, proxy configuration, URL filtering configuration, or Wi-Fi DNS policy or all of them, hence you are out of options.

If it isn't activated, but because you can't flush iptable's chains without root, try removing the VPN app and wiping the cache from recovery. If the problem persists, again - without root - your options are limited - hence you should factory reset your device and not install the VPN app again.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, it's just because of battery optimization.
You just have to go on that particular app in settings and then click on battery optimization. If it shows "not optimized", then it's fine, or else you have to change it to not optimized, then the app will run fine.

Answer (score 0):

Some apps cannot connect to the internet when DuckDuckGo blocks app tracking (WhatsApp/HERE). Most do not have this problem.

Comment: This makes no sense to me.  I use both DuckduckGo and Whatsapp

Answer (score 0):

I think its because your Wifi connection is dicey.  I get this often on my phone often (some apps more than others), where either the network signal or the Wifi signal level is low.

Download a Wifi checking app and walk around your house to find the dead spots.